# String cannot be converted to int array and ASCII

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer, int

I have a problem with my code for ASCII and Morse arrays.
 As long as I know the casting is correct... The code uses functions and casting in order to split every "000000" and translate the numbers into letters and words. I'm not completly sure what is wrong with it but the cmd says:

```
Morse.java:73: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
                            return result;
                                   ^
Morse.java:80: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
                           return result;
                                 ^
```

2 errors  Any help?

```
public class Morse
{
    public static String decode(String txt)
    {
        String[] words = txt.split("0000000");
        String result = "";
            for(int w=0; w<words.length; w++)
            {
                result += processWord(words[w]);
            }
        return result;
    }

    public static String processWord(String word)
    {
        String[] letter = word.split("000");
        String result = "";
            for(int l=0;l<letter.length;l++)
            {
                result += processChar(letter[l]);
            }
        return result;
    }

    public static int processChar(String letters)
    {
        String[] morseLetters = new String[26];
            morseLetters[0] = "10111"; //A
            morseLetters[1] = "111010101"; //B
            morseLetters[2] = "11101011101"; //C
            morseLetters[3] = "1110101"; //D
            morseLetters[4] = "1"; //E
            morseLetters[5] = "101011101"; //F
            morseLetters[6] = "111011101";//G
            morseLetters[7] = "1010101";//H
            morseLetters[8] = "101"; //I
            morseLetters[9] = "1011101110111";//J
            morseLetters[10] = "111010111";// K
            morseLetters[11] = "1011101010";// L
            morseLetters[12] = "1110111"; //M
            morseLetters[13] = "1110001";//N
            morseLetters[14] = "11101110111"; //O
            morseLetters[15] = "10111011101"; //P
            morseLetters[16] = "1110111010111"; // Q
            morseLetters[17] = "1011101"; // R
            morseLetters[18] = "10101";//S
            morseLetters[19] =  "111"; //T
            morseLetters[20] = "1010111";//U
            morseLetters[21] = "101010111"; // V
            morseLetters[22] = "101110111"; //W
            morseLetters[23] = "11101010111"; // x
            morseLetters[24] = "1110101110111"; // Y
            morseLetters[25] = "11101110101";//Z

        String[] morseNumbers = new String[10];
            morseNumbers[0] ="10111011101110111";
            morseNumbers[1] ="101011101110111";
            morseNumbers[2] ="1010101110111";
            morseNumbers[3] ="10101010111";
            morseNumbers[4] ="101010101";
            morseNumbers[5] ="11101010101";
            morseNumbers[6] ="1110111010101";
            morseNumbers[7] ="111011101110101";
            morseNumbers[8] ="11101110111011101";
            morseNumbers[9] ="1110111011101110111";

        int index = find(letters, morseLetters);
            if(index == -1) // not found Look for it in numbers
            {
                index = find(letters, morseNumbers);
                String result = "";
                result += (char)(index + 48);//convert to number
                return result;
            }
              //did find it
            else
            {     
                String result = "";
                result += (char)(index + 65);
                return result;
            }
    }

    public static int find(String needle, String[] haystack)
    {
        for(int h=0; h<haystack.length; h++)
        {
            if(haystack[h].equals(needle))
            {
                return h;
            }
        }
        return -1; // not found!
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String encoded = 
                "10111010001010101110111000111010100010101011101110000000";
        String decoded = decode(encoded);
        System.out.println(decoded);

    }
}


///My output: 
//Morse.java:73: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
//                                return result;
//                                       ^
//Morse.java:80: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
//                                return result;
//                                       ^
//2 errors
```

Comment: Your method is is declarated to return an integer: `public static int processChar(String letters)`, but you are trying to return a `String` which causes the mismatch. Change your method signature to return a String should work: `public static String processChar(String letters)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `processChar` is declared to return `int`

```
public static int processChar(String letters) {...}
```

and in lines 73 and 80 you are trying to return a String. You should change the singnature of method to return `String` object like:

```
public static String processChar(String letters) {...}
```